# How do I use a Batch Script to Move Specific Files with Specific File Contents

Tags: batch-file, command

I am looking to find a file with the contents 'Radiac' in one particular folder and then move all those files to a another folder.

For example: I have might have 3 identical file-names with different extensions like below. Let's say, the content Radiac is only in the jones.pdf file. What I am looking to do is find the file-name with this specific content then xcopy this filename.*.* and its associated extensions to another folder.

jones.pdf

jones.xml

jones.txt

jones.doc

I was able to accomplish that with the following script:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /m /c:"Radiac" *.*') do ^

xcopy "%%a" "C:\"path\to\my\folder"
```

However, I was unable to move files with the .pdf extension. Is there script that will move any file regardless of their extension? I am new to batch scripting so excuse me if I miss anything.

Thanks

Comment: 1) PDF format is a compressed format so there's no plain-text available for `findstr` to see 2) PDFs don't necessarily have the text as a sequence of ASCII characters (it could be a scanned picture). So try googling some command line utilities that can search pdfs.

Comment: Use: `xcopy "%%~Na.*" "C:\"path\to\my\folder"`

Comment: Unbalanced `"` double quotes in `xcopy` command.

Comment: Hi guys, I appreciate the response. I fixed the unbalanced double quotes. I made the adjustments like you recommended: 

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /m /c:"Parker" *.*') do ^
xcopy "%%~na.*" "C:\Test" /y

It only copies one of the pdfs, it leaves the others in the folder. Any ideas? I have attempted the command below as well and same thing.

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /m /c:"Parker" *.*') do echo F|xcopy "%%~na.*" "C:\Test" /y